# How to inject dependency in Entity Framework based controller

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I need to read the `appsetings.json` from inside an auto generate controller based on entity framework and I'm trying to inject the `IConfiguration` interface on it but I cannot find out how.

In the `Startup.cs` file, I just have this:

```
services.AddDbContext<controle_eventosContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
```

and in the controller this:

```
 public ContatosController(controle_eventosContext context)
 {
     _context = context;
 }
```

Where should I inject the `IConfiguration` dependency?

Comment: Why not in controller construction?

Answer (score 0):

As Dhreeraj comment, you can inject in controller constructor, for example:

In your Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange:     true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional:     true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

In your Controller

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AccountController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = Configuration["version"].ToString();
        data += Configuration["Settings:Name"].ToString();
        return Content(data);
    }
}
```

Your appsettings.json:

```
{
    "Version": "1.0.0",
    "Settings": {
        "Name": "App"
    }
}
```

More info:

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/aspnet-core-advanced-18155

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration